# Roslyn code swapping

Tags: c#, roslyn, hotswap

I really like in the asp.net vnext that I can change the code of my controllers while my app is running and just refresh and it will work.

I want to implement the same thing for my app, how does it happen? how can I change the implementation of a type on the fly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.net vNext does this by using a `FileSystemWatcher` to see when a source file changes, and then stopping the app, recompiling, and starting it again.

Comment: There is no way for changing on runtime?

Comment: Not in general. You could load assemblies into different app-domains, and then unload them and load new versions when they change, but in general it's a complex and error-prone mechanism.

Comment: @Yosi: In particular, the entire approach will only work for stateless server applications.